# error: cannot access RemoteMessage when injecting on FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase, dagger

I already setup my dagger Module

```
@Module
interface FCMModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    @UserScope
    fun getFMMessageReceiverService(): FCMMessageReceiverService
}
```

and called `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` in tge FirebaseMessagingService's onCreate

but I always get this error when building

```
error: cannot access RemoteMessage
  class file for com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage not found
  Consult the following stack trace for details.
cannot access RemoteMessage
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I forgot to mention that FCMMessageReceiverService is in a library module. I just copied firebase dependencies to my App module and it now works.